# SharpDX - Modifying the MiniTri example to show a texture

Tags: c#, directx, directx-11, sharpdx

Trying to modify the D3D11 example to draw a texture onto the triangle rather than the colours but all I'm getting is black. Don't know where I'm going wrong :(

Code:

https://pastebin.com/KVMTq9r6

```
    sampler = new SamplerState(device, new SamplerStateDescription()
    {
        Filter = Filter.MinMagMipLinear,
        AddressU = TextureAddressMode.Clamp,
        AddressV = TextureAddressMode.Clamp,
        AddressW = TextureAddressMode.Clamp,
        BorderColor = SharpDX.Color.Black,
        ComparisonFunction = Comparison.Never,
        MaximumAnisotropy = 16,
        MipLodBias = 0,
        MinimumLod = -float.MaxValue,
        MaximumLod = float.MaxValue
    });
```

MiniTri.fx:

https://pastebin.com/0w1myEg0

Comment: probably need more information here, but I assume you are binding the sampler and the texture to the pixel shader pipeline?  And if so, then hard code say a colour like pink to the sampler result to confirm that the sampler is the problem.  Your sampler seems cookie cutter,but I will double check that its set write against my notes.